# Question regarding an inequality in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: inequality

On page 92 in the 4th Edition of Spivak's Calculus, he mentions an inequality while discussing Limits.

|x-3| < 1, or 2 < x < 4

I understand how he got the upper (or < 4) portion of the inequality, but how was the number "2" determined. I might be missing a subtle point here regarding absolute values so I thought I'd ask. Appreciate it in advanced!

Comment: $-1<x-3<1{{}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x-3| < 1$$ is equivalent to $$-1 < x-3 < 1.$$
It may be helpful to read "$|x-3|$" as "the distance between $x$ and $3$."

Comment: Ah, that way of reading it is really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$ |x-3| < 1 \quad\iff\quad -1 < x-3 < 1. $$
Now add $3$ throughout.